# How many Mithril per month can a player expect in FFRK?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

In Final Fantasy Record Keeper, mithril can be considered the "freemium currency" even though the freemium currency are gems. but since in almost all the places 100 gems = 1 mithril (seemingly), I think its safe to make that statement above.

Disregarding the mithril gained by special giveaways, event dungeons, realms dungeons and missions, how many mithril does a player gains per month by playing the game every day?

I think they mostly would come from daily login, but I am really new to the game.

Answer (score 2):

From just logging in daily, you'll typically get 1 every day as part of the daily login bonus, plus 3 every 10 days from the other daily login bonus.

That works out to be about 39 for a 30-day month.

If you just started playing, there's a lot of Mythril you can "mine" from the story dungeons, which also will raise your stamina cap at the same time.  It's really worth doing this so that you can get both of these rewards.

Don't knock the amount of Mythril you can earn from the regularly occurring "Challenge Events" either.  Typically these run for two weeks at a time and overlap by one week, so there's almost always 2 going on at the same time.  It's possible to earn 5-10 Mythril from these, depending on the rewards and the size of the event.

There are also special login events/campaigns, and Mythril gained as a "sorry" when DeNA finds/fixes a bug.

If you factor all this together, you can assume you'll generally have enough Mythril to do an 11x Rare Relic pull each month, plus a few left over for resetting Stamina to run dailies or other special events for orbs/greens.

Comment: That is exactly my concern. It seems that every time a nightmare dungeon opens there is a 11x draw for half price. I was wondering if there is enough mithril to do this half-price plus a regular 11x draw (i.e. 75 mithril per month) sustainably.

Comment: This game is very similiar to Love Live School Idol Festival (and several others i'm sure). In these using the freemium to reload stamina is usually a waste of currency. But good advice.

Comment: @Mindwin, I think 75 in a month is a bit tricky.  My suggestion is to do the half price draw, but then bank the rest of your Mythril.  There are special draw events that occur with MUCH better odds of getting unique soul breaks, which is really the reason to draw relics.  Drawing on normal event banners tends to be a bad deal in the long term.  That said, I get suckered into drawing far more often than I really should :P